# Is it possible to know if a program is being debugged by an external debugger and catch user breakpoints hits / releases

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I have a Win32 application and I need to know if it is being debugged by an external debugger and if yes I would like to catch breakpoint hits / releases events. I looked at `AddVectoredExceptionHandler` API and some others but it seems that breakpoints hits exceptions cannot be catched using the APIs I found when an external debugger is already attached.

`IsDebuggerPresent` is OK to know if you are being debugged but how to catch breakpoint exceptions when an external debugger is already attached?

Actually my application is more or less a real time simulation with time deadline management. I use Windows' timetimeGetTime to handle deadline and I would like to stop time "evolution" when a breakpoint is hit and restart time evolution when breakpoint is released

Does someone have any idea?

Comment: [`IsDebuggerPresent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345.aspx).

Comment: IsDebuggerPresent is OK to know if you are being debugged but how to catch breakpoint exceptions when an external debugger is already attached ?

Comment: As for *catch breakpoint hits / releases events* it's difficult to know what you mean by that. The debuggee isn't going to get any such notifications, since it is paused at a breakpoint. You'd need to debug the debugger presumably. What you failed to explain is why you asked the question. Context would help. What is your motivation?

Comment: Actually my application is more or less a real time simulation with time deadline management. I use windows' `timetimeGetTime` to handle deadline and I would like to stop time "evolution" when the application is being debugged

Comment: Please don't ask your question in comments. I suggest you re-write it. I suggest that you don't ask about your imagined solution, because I doubt it will be useful. Instead ask about how to solve the actual problem.

Comment: It seems like you are measuring wall clock time, but want to measure the time the program is running. There is probably a way to get the user time, which is the time the program has been actually running and not been stuck in sleeps or breakpoints.

Comment: Please spend some time at the [help] to better learn how this site works, and so get the most out of it, thank you

Comment: You cannot intercept breakpoint exceptions, the debugger intercepts the "first chance" notification before you can see it.  And handles it when you resume debugging.  The app is therefore completely unaware that anything happened.  Other than the passage of time.  You need to write your code to be debuggable, giving up on the service guarantee when you know it is possible that a debugger might affect timing.  Could be as simple as #if DEBUG.  Could be as complicated as QueryThreadCycleTime() to make it completely resilient.